# Which parser should be used for efficient data flow in android?

Tags: android, json, jackson, gson

Currently I am working with JSON parser. I read some blogs regarding other parsers like jackson and gson... but unaware of use of them and which one is fastest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had custom requrements for my apps, regarding JSON parsing, and after few itterations, i have developed my own library for JSON parsing/serializing/deserializing using Java generics.

All you need is model class, webservice url and Context. Feel free to check it on  [GitHub](https://github.com/bajicdusko/AndroidJsonProvider), it might be helpful.

Usage example:

```
new AsyncJsonProvider(getActivity(), Planet.class, "http://planetjsonurl.com").shortExecute(new OnDataLoaded() {

    @Override
    public void OnModelLoaded(Model responseModel) {

        Planet p = (Planet) responseModel;
        if (p != null) {
            //your action after data fetching
        }

    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Jackson Parser is the best parsor till now. Its very easy to use , you need to add .jar files for jackson parser in the libs .

Here are many tutorials that will help you to know the implementation .

http://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-processing-api-in-java-example-tutorial

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes